# save items temporarily and then save them in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my class:

```
public class MyItem
{
[Key]
public ItemId{get;set;}
public ItemName{get;set;}
public ItemPrice{get;set;}
}
```

Now I have an add button in my create page:

```
<input type="submit" value="Create" id="Create" name="Create" />
<input type ="submit" value ="Add" id ="Add" name="Create" />
```

I have the following Controller. Here I want to add ItemName and price in my create view in some kind of temporary storage. I don't want to add items in database but want to show the added items in some sort of html helper of table

```
public ActionResult Create(MyItem myitem, string Create)
{
    if (Create == "Add")
    {

//is there any Html helper that will save the
added items and make a view?
//can I do this without using javascript
    }
    else
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Items.Add(myitem);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(myitem);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always use `SESSION` to store the data temporarily and then when user clicks save, you can take data from Session and store in DB

```
public ActionResult Create(MyItem myitem, string Create)
        {
            if (Create == "Add")
            {
                var list = Session[myitem] ?? new List<MyItem>();
                list.Add(myitem);
                Session[myitem] = list;
            }
            else
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var list = Session[myitem]; // add this list to DB
                    db.Items.Add(myitem);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

            return View(myitem);
        }
```

Comment: i want to add multiple items and show them in the view.But adding an another item removes the previously added items.

Comment: you have to add the list back to session. `Session[myitem] = list;` I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use session, the other alternative may be to use a caching solution with a unique key.

- Configure a Key-Value based cache server like memcache, couchbase
- You might need to use the enyim.caching and memcache.dlls in your project
- Add a configuration in web.config for the caching server
- For every unique session exchange a key and keep temporarily saving your values to the key
- After you are sure that everything is in place or when submit is clicked, read everything from cache and save to db.

This is some extra work like for example you'll have to install the cache server and do some extra work. But the advantage is that I would say you'll get lightning fast performance.

May be an overkill, but just wanted to let you know that there are alternatives. If you are looking for a high performance/scalable system, you can consider this. But for an ordinary small project, session would be sufficient as Mr.Comet has mentioned.